# Is it trivial to protect from double free just by LD_PRELOADing a custom malloc/calloc and free?

Tags: memory, c, c++

Can't one just implement a malloc/calloc wrapper that adds the returned pointer address to a global hash table prior to returning, and then a free wrapper that checks for the presence of the pointer in the table prior to freeing (returning early if it isn't present, and removing it if it is), and then LD_PRELOAD these malloc/calloc and free functions with a program like Firefox, in order to protect from double frees? Is there a reason why the standard malloc/calloc and free functions don't use such a technique, or why there isn't a secure variant that is suggested similarly to how strcpy_s is suggested in place of strcpy?

Comment: "LD_PRELOAD these malloc/calloc and free functions with a program like Firefox" - What does Firefox have to do with any of this?

Comment: Always start with the assumption that there are people with way more experience who already considered any possible trivial solution. As such, it's better to ask "Why is malloc/callor not implemented in a way that prevents double free vulnerabilities?"

Comment: Do not try to use `LD_PRELOAD` for memory allocator functions in Firefox! That might actually reduce security. You'd need to use Firefox's [`replace_malloc`](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/memory/build/replace_malloc.h) functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The reason double free is a vulnerability is that the memory has been reallocated for something else before the second `free`. Any such wrapper would have no way of knowing whether the `free` was intended for the first or second allocation of memory at that address.

Comment: It's removed from the hash table if it is present during the first free.

Comment: @cyborg But it will get re-added during the second malloc.

Comment: if you free after the second malloc, and the second malloc happened after the first free, I don't see why it would be a double free.

Comment: @cyborg Because the second free was on the old pointer, while the application is still using the memory via the new pointer. If you don't understand that, then you don't understand double frees at all.

Comment: What if you also wrap the free function to point the pointer to NULL?

Comment: @cyborg That's impossible, because `free` takes the pointer by value.

Comment: You can make a secureFree that takes a pointer to the pointer, passes the dereferenced pointer pointer to free, and then points the pointer it dereferences to to NULL.

Comment: @cyborg But such a function would be called differently than `free`, so you couldn't just swap it in with `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Can you cast a pointer to a pointer pointer internally to the function? So it still just takes a pointer like free, but then internally casts it to pointer pointer?

Comment: @cyborg That's not how function calls work. You could get **a** pointer to a pointer that way, but it wouldn't point to the right place.

Comment: You're right -- it would need to take a void* like free, then internally make a void ** to it, pass it to free as the void*, and then dereference the void ** and set it to NULL. I accepted your answer and don't want to clog up comments, but please let me know if that last solution will work.

Comment: @cyborg You can't "make a void **" in a useful way, if you're only passed a `void *`. If you try, you'll end up with a pointer to your own local variable, instead of to the caller's copy.